# Selecting all columns except geometry using Virtual Layer in QGIS

Tags: qgis, sql, fields-attributes, select, virtual-layer

Is it possible to select all columns except geometry using Virtual Layers in QGIS?

For example I have this (simplified) query:

```sql
Select
    *,
    st_buffer(geometry, 100)
From
    mypolygons
```

It does not work. It does not buffer at all. But using the (simplified) query as follows does buffer all polygons as intended:

```sql
Select
    id,
    name,
    st_buffer(geometry, 100)
From
    mypolygons
```

Now the issue is, that if I have polygons with a lot of columns I need them to type in all manually. Is there a way to avoid this?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It does work as intended, and it is only a display issue.

To make is work, just give a name to the buffered geometry and specify this name as being the spatial column.

Otherwise, the Virtual Layer has two geometry columns, the original `geometry` and the new `st_buffer(geometry)` and the 1st one is picked-up for display.

```sql
Select
    *,
    st_buffer(geometry, 100) as geo2
From
    mypolygons
```

[image]