# QGIS Aggregate 1x1km grid into 10x10km for Brazilian Land-Use Data

Tags: qgis, shapefile, land-cover

I'm working with an externally-provided dataset, which is a 1x1km grid of the Brazilian Amazon.

Each grid cell contains information on the percentage covered by various land-covers e.g. 30% Pasture, 25% Forest, 10% Freshwater etc. However, due to the processing time, I'm looking to find a way to aggregate this into grid with larger cells, for example 10x10km, where each grid cell takes the average land-cover percentage for all of the 1x1km cells that comprise it. I'm sure that issues will arise from such a transformation - but could anyone please guide on how to go about doing this in QGIS?

Answer (score 1):

**Step 1.** Create a bigger grid 10*10 km using the ["Create grid"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorcreation.html#create-grid) tool with the following setting:

```
Grid type : 2 — Rectangle (polygon)
Grid extent : Calculate from layer : 1x1km grid of the Brazilian Amazon.
Horizontal spacing : 10 km
Vertical spacing : 10 km
```

**Step 2.** Apply the ["Join attributes by location (summary)"](https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/processing_algs/qgis/vectorgeneral.html#join-attributes-by-location-summary).

Comment: Alternatively can be an application of the Virtual Layer as shown here : https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/430481/99589