# Is there non spatial Virtual Layer in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, attribute-table, mapinfo, virtual-layer

I have two users working on the same project with identical shapefiles but in a different geographic area.

User 1 is working in Area 1
User 2 is working on Area 2

When using MapInfo I used to keep track of the progress by creating an SQL `SELECT` and then `GROUP BY`. The view was refreshed each time I opened the Workspace.

How may I replicate this in QGIS?

Comment: You can look this documentation part : https://docs.qgis.org/3.22/en/docs/user_manual/managing_data_source/create_layers.html?#creating-virtual-layers

Comment: Is there a non spatial virtual layer in QGIS? - Yes, just dont add geometry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As was mentioned by @J.Monticolo in his comment it is possible to exclude the geometry simply by choosing *'No geometry'* in the *'Geometry'* tab

[image: option1]

---

Also as was mentioned by @MrXsquared in his/her comment: simply do not add the geometry.

```sql
SELECT "field1", "field2"
FROM "layer"
```

Also pay attention to this thread : [Selecting all columns except geometry using Virtual Layer in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313331/selecting-all-columns-except-geometry-using-virtual-layer-in-qgis)

Comment: even by adding a geometry column, there is an explicit option in the dialog : `No geometry`, for me it's very explicit.