# QGIS - Merging two tables and make lines

Tags: qgis, sql, query

I need help with merging two table and create geometry.
I have two points layer with features tables and try create polyline layer.
When I create virtual layer with next querry then result is polyline layer with specifying columns:

```
select a.field1, b.field2, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
from a
inner join
b On b.id = a.id
```

But when I try select all field from tables result is **point layer** with features:

```
select a.*, b.*, makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry
from a
inner join
b On b.id = a.id
```

There is a way to create lines and obtain all column in new layer?

Comment: try to `makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as line_geom` and specify to QGIS that `line_geom` is the geometry field.

Comment: related: https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/313331/selecting-all-columns-except-geometry-using-virtual-layer-in-qgis

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem. Problem was in order of elements in select statement.
This query work perfectly:

```
select makeline(a.geometry, b.geometry) as geometry,  a.*, b.*
from a
inner join
b On b.id = a.id
```

Comment: I thing there is some kind of bug: query ignoring specify column and make geometry type based on first column of geometry in select statement.

Comment: If `geometry` is literal column name in both tables, the query creates a table with three columns named `geometry`. This typically leads to confusion and errors (and sometimes is not supported at all). I would exclude the a.geometry and b.geometry from query results if this is the case. Some DBMS support syntax like
`a.* EXCEPT (geometry), a.geometry AS a_geometry` for that.